# Kubernetes API server drops watch connections

Tags: http, kubernetes

After 30-45 minutes, chunked HTTP connection to API server is dropped:

```
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: http-alt (8080), Dst Port: 55782 (55782), Seq: 751, Ack: 88, Len: 0
.... 0000 0001 0001 = Flags: 0x011 (FIN, ACK)
```

This happens regardless of the activity level, i.e. it happens for connections that were idle for a long time but also for the ones that had notifications coming for the whole duration of the connection. HTTP 1.0 (with `Connection: Keep-Alive` header) just ends the original request, while HTTP 1.1, which is keepalive by default, sends `400 Bad Request` before dropping the connection.

Is it possible to get a watch connection which remains alive for a long period of time?

Comment: Which K8S version and which environment? You might be hitting https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8700 but since you already raised an issue on the repo that's prolly the best place to have the discussion ;)

Comment: version 1.0.6, thanks I will also update the github issue

Comment: and the environment is CoreOS:

```CoreOS
$ uname -a Linux ip-10-10-0-20.ec2.internal 4.0.5 #2 SMP Fri Jul 10 06:25:01 UTC 2015 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you're certain your client properly handles disconnections, you can use the following kube-apiserver flag to control how long apiserver lets the watches stay open:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/admin/kube-apiserver.md

`--min-request-timeout=1800: An optional field indicating the minimum number of seconds a handler must keep a request open before timing it out. Currently only honored by the watch request handler, which picks a randomized value above this number as the connection timeout, to spread out load.`

Test with a small value, run in production with a large value.

Answer (score 1):

Watches are supposed to drop periodically - they are just long HTTP GET operations underneath, with timeouts.  It's intentional.  Is it causing a problem?

Comment: I understand they are GET, but I was expecting them to last until the client decides to drop the connection. So, yes it is causing a problem. Is websocket the only way to have control over how long does a watch connection last? Or is there no way?

Comment: Robust clients *must* be able to recover from dropped connections. In testing we actually set the timeout value to ~5 minutes to ensure that code path is exercised. Once your client handles this case, though, it makes sense to allow very long watch periods in production; there are flags on kube-apiserver to let you do this.

Comment: @lavalamp: I recover, of course, but we have a time-sensitive application where any unnecessary disconnect is undesirable. In any case, is `--long-running-request-regexp` what you are referring to?